# How to set to a element height with jquery in this code

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code and am trying to set value of document height variable to height parameter in a html element. I labeled it with "HERE"

```
var height = $(document).height();
```

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; color: #3B5998; outline:0;"
   href="page.php?sesion=8431545&catid=19"
   rel="lightframe[|width:1080px; height: HERE;]">Title
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$("#lightframe").attr("rel","lightframe[|width:1080px; height: "+$(document).height()+";]");

<a id="lightframe" style="text-decoration:none; color: #3B5998; outline:0;"
   href="page.php?sesion=8431545&catid=19"
   rel="">Title
</a>
```

Comment: Ian, one more question please. I have a more than one links on page, this is works perfect for one link, how i should use this solution for multiple links on an page?

Comment: Will they all be given the same dimensions? If so change the ID selector to a class selector and give the class to all of them.

Comment: Thank you. This is awesome, I've learned new thing today thanks to you
Cheers, have a great day

Answer (score 1):

```
var height = $(document).height();

$(".tall-anchor").height(height);
```

---

```
<a class="tall-anchor"
   style="text-decoration:none; color: #3B5998; outline:0;"
   href="page.php?sesion=8431545&catid=19"
   rel="lightframe[|width:1080px;]">Title
</a>
```

Comment: Close but... i need to replace text HERE with value of variable height.

Comment: @user3051153 Oh, sorry. I read `am trying to set value of document height variable to height parameter in a html element` and answered accordingly. What you want is going to require parsing that `rel` attribute and setting the text of the relevant portion to whatever you want.